# Search box/button similar to CTRL + F in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out what is the actual code for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> command but can't find it. The closest I found is pasted below; the only problem is that I can't change the range properly.

I would like to change the range to look for values in the whole sheet on only column A. I would also like, if instead of returning a message saying it found the value in X row, I would prefer if it actually goes to it. I'm new to VBA and I'm having the hardest time understanding active ranges.

```
Sub PlayMacro()

  Dim Prompt As String
  Dim RetValue As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  Prompt = ""

  ' The macro recorder has used the active worksheet.  This says which
  ' worksheet is to be used whether it is active or not.  Change "Sheet4"
  ' to the name of your worksheet.
  With Sheets("Sheet4")

    ' This will loop forever unless a statement within
    ' the loop exits the Do.
    Do While True

      RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Give me a value to look for")
      'RetValue will be empty if you click cancel
      If RetValue = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If

      ' I do not wish to active the cell containing the required value.
      ' I want to know where it is.
      Set Rng = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:=RetValue, After:=.Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        ' The entered value could not be found
        Prompt = "I could not find """ & RetValue & """"
      Else
        ' The entered value was found
        RowCrnt = Rng.Row
        Prompt = "I found """ & RetValue & """ on row " & RowCrnt
      End If
      Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
    Loop

  End With
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It's searching just Column A. If `Rng` is found, then you can just do `Rng.select` to activate the cell where the value is found. You can also do say `If Rng.Row = 3 Then ...` if the value is in row three...?  If you want to search the whole sheet, just do `Set Rng = .Cells.Find(...`

Comment: FWIW `LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole` is a strange combination to be searching for, especially when the user prompt is "Give me a **value** to look for" - are you sure you don't want to look in `xlValues`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the last part of your code to:

```
  If Rng Is Nothing Then
    ' The entered value could not be found
    Prompt = "I could not find """ & RetValue & """" & vbLf
  Else
    ' The entered value was found
    Application.GoTo Rng
    Prompt = ""
  End If
Loop
```

I think you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[excel-finder-macro](https://github.com/freginold/Excel-finder-macro) (on GitHub) is an Excel macro I made a while back, that you can play around with and change the range for.

Since it's just a VBA macro, you can customize it however you want, including restricting the search to only column A. From the README:

> The macro currently searches all cells within a range from the farthest row that has a value in column A, all the way over to column ZZ. It can be made to search farther over, or search rows based on a different column, by changing the  `cellRange`  variable. The macro is case-insensitive and will find a character or partial string inside other text.

`cellRange` is by default set up as:

```
numRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 
cellRange = "a1:zz" & numRows
```

You can play with the values and constrain them any way you want. For example, to only search in column A, you could change `cellRange` to:

```
cellRange = "a1:a1" & numRows
```

This finder macro also goes to the found value, like you said you wanted, and highlights it.

The code is open source and public domain, so feel free to use and/or change it.

Comment: thank you very much, your code is great. There is one little issue im having with it, its not looking through formulas. i just realized that the values im trying to find with the code are being reference from a different sheet so they are formulas. unfortunately i cannot just copy and paste into values, they have to remain formulas. do you know if there's something i can add to your code to make it look though formulas?

Comment: @S.MART Are you trying to search for text in the formulas (i.e. `LookIn:=xlFormulas`), or search for text in the values calculated by those formulas (i.e. `LookIn:=xlValues`)?  E.g.  If you had a formula in Excel of `="ab"&"cd"` then searching for `"abcd"` in `xlFormulas` would fail, but searching for it in `xlValues` will find it.